# My Firefox window is not appearing even though I can see the process. What's going on?

Tags: windows, firefox

New Laptop HP8760W I have installed Firefox latest beta version. When I am trying to start the Firefox I see under processes it is running but window is not popping up.

I tried all possible ways of running CCleaner cleaning registry – no use, tried uninstalling, reinstalling, restarting, nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried running a non-beta version?

Comment: Are you on the administrator account?

Comment: tried non-beta version and I am running on administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **any** registry cleaner help fixing this problem as well as many others... The best effect of registry cleaners is a *placebo* effect to say the less...

What you can try is to follow the troubleshooting procedure from Mozilla:

[Troubleshoot and diagnose Firefox problems - support Mozilla.org](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems)

Please note this problem may be related to Windows conditions and not a Firefox problem such as bad sectors, malwares or even some security software parameters...

Comment: tried ... none worked.